# No se ha encontrado ningún recurso HTTP que coincida con la URI de la solicitud

Tags: c#, rest, postman

Me aparece ese error al tratar de acceder a la ruta definida en mi controller

la cual está en un método post que envía y recibe unos parámetros como lo indico en el siguiente código:

```
 [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/ConsultasGP/ConsultasPuertos")]

    public async Task<IList<PuertosGP>> ConsultasPuertos([FromUri]string id, 
         [FromBody] List<PuertosGP> lstPuertosGP, [FromUri]DateTime fecha)
        { ..... demas codigo
```

al hacer una prueba en POSTMAN Sale el siguiente "No se ha encontrado ningún recurso HTTP que coincida con la URI de la solicitud "http://localhost:24175/api/ConsultasGP/ConsultasPuertos"

En mi WebApiConfig.cs se encuentra de esta forma configurado:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Me pudieran explicar cual es el error que estoy cometiendo?

No entiendo cual es el error.

**UPDATE** falto agregar el [FromUri] y [FromBody] ya que esto hay que enviarle el Id que es un string

Comment: Que tipo de prueba POSTMAN estás haciendo, POST o GET?

Comment: @RafaelAcosta haciendo POST

Comment: El `DateTime fecha` lo envías en la URL [FromUri]?, veo que has editado la pregunta

Comment: @RafaelAcosta si ademas de esto tengo otro metodo api/ConsultasGP/ConsultasPuertosPorFecha que tiene un [FromUri] DateTime FechaConsulta que si entraba a ese metodo y ya no!

Comment: Recuerda siempre valorar las respuestas que te han ayudado a solucionar tu pregunta, con eso estarás colaborando con la buena salud de este sitio.

Comment: Me pasó lo mismo en su momento y era que a la clase le puse Creacliente y debía ser CreaclienteController.cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes indicar en la ruta que has definido para la Acción `ConsultasPuertos(...)`, los parámetros que vendrán desde la Url (`id` y `fecha`):

```
[Route("api/ConsultasGP/ConsultasPuertos/{id}/{fecha}")]
```

Y por otra parte, en la configuración de rutas, indicar estos parámetros como opcionales:

```
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}/{fecha}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, fecha = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Comment: tengo otro metodo api/ConsultasGP/ConsultasPuertosPorFecha tengo que definir los parametros en el web api? routeTemplate: api/{controller}/{action}/{id}/{fecha} {FechaConsulta }*??

Comment: @ger No hace falta, solo cambia el parámetro de entrada `[FromUri] DateTime FechaConsulta` por `[FromUri] DateTime fecha` y el **Route** sería `[Route("api/ConsultasGP/ConsultasPuertosPorFecha/{id}/{fecha}")]`.